# How to put Javascript inside a DIv Tag

Tags: javascript, prototype

See the site here

http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index

After selecting a particular area , i am updating the Div with this code

```
$('dateRange').update(dateData[xmin] + ' - ' + dateData[xmax]);


       <div id="dateRange">
    </div>
```

**Actually my question is after updating the div , i want to execute a some function .
So is it possible to keep Javascript inside the div tag ??**

Because if i keep the function after this line

```
        $('dateRange').update(dateData[xmin] + ' - ' + dateData[xmax]);
alert(date1);
```

alert(date2);
**the code is geting executed a number of times (In this case the alerts are coming as soon as the mouse is moved on chart )**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to keep Javascript inside the div tag ? YES
you need to put your script inside `<script>` tag and pass it to JQuery update method.